# Flutter - setState Not Using New Data

Tags: caching, dart, widget, flutter, setstate

I have a screen which I pass data back to like so:

```
final myUpdatedObject = await Navigator.of(context).push(...);
setState({
  object = myUpdatedObject;
});
```

Having checked with a simple `print` at all places in my widget body that my object is used, the new data is present after it is passed back by the `Navigator` and `setState` is called.

However, when the widget is rebuilt, even though the new data is apparently there, it is not reflected in the UI changes, it shows old data.

Is this some sort of caching in debug mode? Whats causing this issue?

Comment: are you creating new object (`myUpdatedObject`) in your new Page before poping or you are sending the same object reference with different value?

Comment: Its a new object. I convert it to a `Map` and back into its object class in order to have a completely new reference.

Comment: There is no way of telling unless you show us how are you using your map

Comment: If it is a new reference it should re-render the widget. Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 1):

The example below starts with a `Map` named `textMessageMap` with a `message` key that populates a `Text` Widget with 'Home'. Tap the `FloatingActionButton` and you'll navigate to `SecondScreen`. If you tap the 'Go back!' button in `SecondScreen`, the `message` key in `textMessageMap` will be updated to read 'Second Screen'. If you tap the back button on the `Scaffold` of `SecondScreen`, `textMessageMap` will be nulled out. Calling `setState` updates the UI appropriately. See if your implementation is different.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<String, String> textMessageMap = {'message': 'Home'};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              '${textMessageMap != null ? textMessageMap['message'] : 'map is null'}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _launchSecondScreen();
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchSecondScreen() async {
    final value = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<Map<String, String>>(
            builder: (BuildContext _) => SecondScreen()));
    setState(() {
      textMessageMap = value;
    });
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to the first screen by popping the current route
            // off the stack. The text 'Second Screen' will replace 'Home'.
            // If you hit the scaffold's back button, the return value will be
            // null instead.
            final map = {'message': 'Second Screen'};
            Navigator.pop(context, map);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```